# Using hoverIntent with .on or delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you use hoverIntent with this:

```
    $mainNav.on('mouseenter', '.hEvent', function () {
       //Do stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the "**selector**" option for event delegation.

```
$mainNav.hoverIntent({
        over: function() {

        },
        out: function(){

        },
        selector: '.hEvent'
});
```

Source: [hoverIntent Documentation](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is a bit tricky to use things like 'hover' or 'hoverIntent' directly using delegate(), because hover is not an ACTUAL event, but it is composed of two different events, namely **mouseenter**, and **mouseleave**. Therefore, *hover* is actually a pseudo-event. This information can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Now, about handling the pseudo-event:
This should work, and the code is also self-explanatory.
Suppose you need to bind the hoverIntent to ***#child***

```
    $('#parent').delegate(
       '#child',
       'hoverIntent',
       function (evt) {
           if (evt.type === 'mouseenter')
               $(this).find('.tooltip').fadeIn();
           else
               $(this).find('.tooltip').hide();
   });
```

Hope this helps. :D

Answer (score -1):

.hEvent is being used as the selector, right?  The hoverIntent plug-in, from what I understand, has an option called `over` that takes a function, which is synonymous with the onMouseOver (like the jQuery MouseEnter event).

Wouldn't you be able to use:

```
$(".hEvent").hoverIntent(over: function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Yes, hEvent is the the selector and $mainNav is its parent, the reason i was using .on is bc i had several .hEvent's so i didnt want to add a event listener to each .hEvent, so is there still no way to incorporate event delegation with hoverintent

Comment: Can you use a more specific selector to include the parent?

Comment: even if I am more specific on my selector, I still have several .hEvent on the page, so wouldn't i still be attaching several event listeners to the page instead of just one when i use .on